# Does Postgres ever require a naked field without single quotes?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have this query:

```
UPDATE user_map_table SET  user_id = '1', value = '{"bob":"diane"}', key = 'couple', value_type = 'string', added = 'false' WHERE user_id = 1
```

it worked fine. The thing is the user_id column is an int column, and the added column is a boolean column. Postgres doesn't seem to care that I put single-quotes around the '1' and 'false'.  Is there ever a time where single quotes will make Postgres barf?

One obvious answer might be if you have extra whitespace:  `' 1'` or `'false '`, but other than that?

Comment: Postgres is implicitly converting your string to an integer. It's better if you don't do it or rely on it.

Comment: it might be better but if it's not that important could keep it as a string. one path:

json int -> golang int -> postgres int  

another path:

json string -> go string -> postgres int

Answer (score 2):

With overloaded functions (same name but different arguments), there can be cases where they mean different things. But you should probably avoid creating such cases.

```
create function j(int) returns int language SQL as $$ select 1-$1 $$;
create function j(text) returns int language SQL as $$ select 7-$1::int $$;
select j('5');
 2
select j(5);
 -4
```

Answer (score 1):

from the postgres documentation:

> Boolean constants can be represented in SQL queries by the SQL key words TRUE, FALSE, and NULL.
>
> The datatype input function for type boolean accepts these string

```
representations for the "true" state:
true
yes
on
1

and these representations for the "false" state:
false
no
off
0
```

> Unique prefixes of these strings are also accepted, for example t or n. Leading or trailing whitespace is ignored, and case does not matter.
> The datatype output function for type boolean always emits either t or f, as shown in Example 8-2.

[link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datatype-boolean.html)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: when defining a column, Postgres can try and parse your string to match the data type that you've used. for example, a timestamp column that gets a string with '2020-02-01' will be parsed to 2020-02-01 00:00:00
meaning, when using a boolean supported value, Postgres will try and parse the value, thus, '1' / 'true' / true / yes / 'on' will all result in a positive boolean value...